# How to take snapshot with curl request (bash script) from a dahua IP camera?

Tags: bash, curl

How can one use a curl request to take a picture with a Dahua IP camera? Use a timestamp for the file name.

Answer (score 0):

## the script

```
#!/bin/bash

ip="192.168.1.14"
port="31"
user="admin"
password="admin31"

curl --user "$user:$password" "http://$ip:$port/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?1" --digest -o "$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).JPG" -s
```

## usage

```
sudo chmod +x takesnap.sh
./takesnap.sh
```